# Regular expression for all strings with even length and not containing “ab” and “ba”

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, regular-expressions

I have a problem with this question:

we have a language with alphabet {a, b, c}, all strings in this language have even length and does not contain any substring "ab" and "ba" for example these strings acceptable: "accb", "aa", "bb", "bcac", and these strings not acceptable "ccab", "abca", "cabc" and so on.. actually I think this is not regular language but I can't prove it, anyone can help me by give a regular expression for this language or prove that this language is not regular? or any help that I can figure out how I must think about it.

i tryed (aa)*(cc)*(bb)*+(bb)*(cc)*(aa)*+(ac+ca)*+(bc+cb)* and ((a+c)(a+c))*+((b+c)(b+c))*+(ac+bc)*(ca+cb)*+(ca+cb)*(ac+bc)* but this not work

Comment: Sounds regular to me.  Try to construct an NDFA that recognizes it.

Comment: @saulspatz, actually i does not familiar with NDFA, could you check this?

Comment: Are you familiar with finite-state automata at all?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm familiar with regular languages, context-free grammars and normal forms

Comment: So you know regular grammars too, I assume.

Comment: yes i know regular grammars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $7$ non-terminals.  $S$ is the initial state, $T,\ U,$ and $V$ all indicate that an odd number of characters have been read, and that the last character read was $a$, $b$, or $c$, respectively.  Similarly, $X,\ Y$, and $Z$ indicate that an even number of characters have been read, and that the last character read was $a$, $b$, or $c$, respectively. I use $\lambda$ for the empty string.  $S,\ X,\ Y$, and $Z$ are accepting states, so we have the productions $$S\to\lambda\\  X\to\lambda\\ Y\to\lambda\\ Z\to\lambda\\ $$
Also we, have $$S\to aT\\S\to bU\\S\to cV\\T\to aX\\T\to cZ\\U\to bY\\U\to cZ\\V\to aX\\V\to bY\\V\to cZ\\$$

I trust you see how I arrived at these.  If we get a $b$ in state $T$ or an $a$ in state $U$ then we've seen a forbidden substring, so there are no productions corresponding to these possibilities.

It remains to determine the productions with $X,\ Y$ or $z$ on the left-hand side.  I leave it to you to supply those.

**EDIT** Reading this over, I see that I've slipped into the language of automata at times.  I hope it's obvious what I mean.  If not, ping me.

**EDIT**

When I wrote this, I though you were mainly concerned with whether or not the language is regular, but it's apparent from your comments that you're mostly concerned with getting a regex.  Remember that the complement of a regular language is regular.  So we want the complement of the union of

```
-set of strings containing $ab$
-set of strings containing $ba$
-set of strings with an odd number of characters
```

So, if you can make regexes for these three languages, you can combine them to construct the regex you seek.

**EDIT**

The previous edit is wrong.  The discussion prior to theorem $4.5$ in [Hopcroft, Motwani and Ullman](http://ce.sharif.edu/courses/94-95/1/ce414-2/resources/root/Text%20Books/Automata/John%20E.%20Hopcroft,%20Rajeev%20Motwani,%20Jeffrey%20D.%20Ullman-Introduction%20to%20Automata%20Theory,%20Languages,%20and%20Computations-Prentice%20Hall%20(2006).pdf) says that you can't do it that way.  You have to convert the regex to a DFA, construct a DFA that recognizes the complement, and then convert the new DFA to a regex.  I think any regex for this language will be exceedingly long and complicated.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i read it and honestly i'm confused how i can convert it to regular expression

Comment: and i don't know what is automata

Comment: It's a grammar.

Comment: can you help me how i can convert it to regural expression or give me regular expression that works with this language?

Comment: The typical path is to convert a regular grammar to an automaton, and then convert the automaton to a regex.  I don't  know an algorithm that skips the automaton.

Answer (score 0):

Your language is regular. All you need to know is that regular languages are closed under Boolean operations (union, intersection, complement, set difference, ...)

Let $A = \{a,b,c\}$ be the alphabet. The set $E$ of words of even length is $(AA)^*$ and hence it is regular. The set $F$ of words containing either $ab$ or $ba$ as a factor is $A^*(ab + ba)A^*$ and it is also regular. Your language is $E \setminus F$ and thus it is regular.